# Core Data can't save anything

Tags: core-data, save, entity

I have started learning Core Data programming and I have a problem. The book that helped me in my studies is written for XCode3, and I'm using XCode4. I surfed on the Net and found [this](http://www.swampfoetus.net/chapter-7-fail/#_comments) article . I've done everything just like it's written there and created my entity just like it's written in the book. To enable the save action I was told to CTRL+drag the Save menu item to the AppDelegate in my nib. I did so, but when I make changes in the program and then save it when I reopen it it seems that nothing has saved. How could I solve this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to connect save button with an action handler. It must have this structure:

`.h file`

```
@interface YourClass : UITableViewController 
//... ivars, properties    
-(IBAction)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender;
@end
```

`.m file`

```
-(void)saveButtonPressed:(id)sender {
   [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
}
```

Now the ctrl-dragging should work. Drag from the button to the controller. In the resulting black popup you should be able to select `saveButtonPressed`.

---

**Edit**

An even better method is to do this: open the split view controller. On the left you have your storyboard / IB with button, on the right the .h file of your view controller class. Now control drag from the button to a space above `@end` in the .h file. In the popup, select "Action" (not "Outlet"), name it e.g. `saveButtonPressed`. Press OK and Xcode will generate automatically all of the above. Now just fill in the save instruction in your new button handler.

Comment: This didn't help me :( BTW why do you think this method is better than that which is automatically generated when you make a core data project in XCode?

Comment: I did everything as you told, but still I open .app file, make some changes, save it, exit and when I open the file again I can see that nothing has saved

Comment: Put a breakpoint at the save statement and check that it is being called.